# AsyncTask freezing UI during database operation

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm starting an asyncTask to perform a lengthy operation (more than 1 second) in the database.

Right after I start the AsyncTask I want to finish the activity it's in and move on. The problem is that the activity is hanging until the AsyncTask finishes.

I inject the task:

```
 @Inject
 CreateMultipleTransactionsTask mCreateMultipleTransactionTask;
```

and later after I click a button I call:

```
mCreateMultipleTransactionTask.execute(transaction);
```

and immediately below I call `finish()` to close the activity. However, I see that the `finish()` is being called but the activity is still there.

Here's the Task:

```
public class CreateMultipleTransactionsTask extends AsyncTask<Transaction, Void, List<Long>> {

    @Inject
    TransactionDataSource mDataSource;

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Long> longs) {
        super.onPostExecute(longs);
        mDataSource.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Long> doInBackground(Transaction... params) {
        return mDataSource.createRepeatingTransaction(params[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case you should use a service, since AsyncTask is always tied to an activity. Killing the activity before the AsyncTask is not finished, is not recommended.

Comment: As @LazyNinja said you have to use Android service.

Comment: @LazyNinja Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Killing your activity right after starting the AsyncTask , won't stop the AsyncTask from running to completion. 
It will hold onto a reference to the Activity, keeping the Activity from being garbage-collected.
In your case, I recommend using a `service`.
The service will keep running even if your finish your activity. Just don't bind it to the activity you are going to kill.